# C# Entity Framework Entity State Modified

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

I am pretty new to C#. I am trying to make an user profile database and display it in a WPF listview in C#, with Entity Framework code-first.

I have managed to add and delete profiles to the database, and display them.
I got stuck on modifying an existing object and after a while of trying to make it work, the closest thing I got was that the selected object (selected in the listview) makes the one above it receive the update.

Here is the code for the "Save" button

```
private void btnSaveChanges_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        using (UsersContext ctx = new UsersContext())
        {
            User user = ctx.Users.Find(UsersTable.SelectedIndex);

            if (user != null)
            {
                user.Name = txtUName.Text;
                user.IdNumber = txtIdNumber.Text;
                user.Department = txtDepartment.Text;
                user.Position = txtPosition.Text;
                user.Username = txtUsername.Text;
                user.Password = pwbPassword.Password;
            }

            ctx.Entry(user).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
            ctx.SaveChanges();

            txtUName.Text = "";
            txtIdNumber.Text = "";
            txtDepartment.Text = "";
            txtPosition.Text = "";
            txtUsername.Text = "";
            pwbPassword.Password = "";

            UsersTable.ItemsSource = ctx.Users.ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is when I select and try to update the first entry to the database (the first row in listview), I get the "ArgumentNullException was unhandled" error/exception.

Visual Studio indicates that the error comes from:

```
ctx.Entry(user).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
```

Also, I can't save changes on my last row because when I select it the changes are saved on the row above it.

I would really appreciate some help.

Comment: @Christian  consider case when `ctx.Users.Find(UsersTable.SelectedIndex);` returns `null`, in this case `ctx.Entry(user)` will also returns `null` and you get `NullReferenceException` when you acess `State` property.

Comment: (1) `if (user != null) { ..}`, else?? (2) `ctx.Users.Find` expects `Id`, not index `UsersTable.SelectedIndex`)

Answer (score 0):

The exception comes from

```
ctx.Entry(user).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
```

because you did not include that line inside your null check. So if user is null, it will cause that exception.

As for the general problem: I would not try to select the record using the SelectedIndex. If you have a unique key, then get the selected user with SelectedItem and retrieve your user from the DB like this:

```
User user = ctx.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == selectedUser.Id);
```

Also there is no need to change the state manually. EF will track the changes for you and automatically save it if necessary when you call  `ctx.SaveChanges();`

Another thing you might look into is using a more MVVM like approach and use view models to bind to your list and to bind the user to your textboxes. Depending on your application design you might also consider having only one DbContext instead of creating a new one every time you save. This way you do not need to fetch the users from the database again when you save because EF already tracks them.

Comment: what part of C# should i study to understand the expression  "User user = ctx.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == selectedUser.Id);"?What does selectedUser.Id represents?  Also thanks to everybody who answered!